# Big-O Analysis of Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis, mergesort

It seems to be a searching algorithm based off of Mergesort. It is to be used on a sorted array of numbers. Is the Big-O complexity still O(n log n)?

```
public static boolean fastSearch(int[] data, int min, int max, int target)
{
     int N = data.length;
     boolean found = false;
     int midpoint = (min+max)/2; // determine the midpoint

     if (data[midpoint] == target) {
          found = true;
     } else {
          if (data[midpoint] > target) {
               if (min <= midpoint - 1) {
                    // Recursion on the left half of the array
                    found = fastSearch(data, min, midpoint-1, target);
               }
          } else {
               if (midpoint + 1 <= max) {
                    // Recursion on the right half of the array
                    found = fastSearch(data, midpoint+1, max, target);
               }
          }
     }
     return found;
}
```

This is my own analysis I did, I just want to confirm if I'm correct or not:

Each pass through the data doubles the size of the subsections. These need to be repeatedly doubled until it finds the target. It takes log(n) doublings, and each pass of the data is proportional to the number of items. So, it is O(n log n).

Comment: Can you please indent code and add braces?  I'm getting googly-eyed trying to be a human compiler.

Comment: "and each pass of the data is proportional to the number of items". You sure about this? :)

Comment: If this is an implementation of [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), the run time should be `O(log n)`. That being said, I can't say that this is a proper implementation based on your formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a normal binary search algorithm to me, which is known to have `O(log n)` complexity (except it returns whether value was found, not its position). You basically "visits" at most `log n` of entries of array:

- first you visit and check point in the middle, and check if its the one you sought,
- if not, you limits your searching to "lower" or "upper" sought part of array,
- so you are slicing table in half and then choosing only one of those parts, so long there would be only 1 element left (worst case scenario - sought element would be found earlier),
- how many times you can do that? `n/2/2/2/2/.../2 = 1` - the amount of `/2` would be `log n`.

It's not a strict analysis. There are likely to be some off-by-one errors as well as no boundary condition checking, but the final result would surely be `O(log n)`.

Of course, we have to assume that `data` array is sorted and `n = max - min` (and `min < max`). Otherwise that would be garbage.

BTW: `f(n) = O(log n)` means that `log n` (from some point) is kind of upper limit of `f(n)` (with possibly some positive constant factor). `f(n) = O(n log n)` would mean that same for `n log n`. So yeah, if its limited by `log n` it surely is limited by `n log n` (since `f(n) <= c1(log n) <= c2(n log n)` for all n greather that some N) but that's not the answer you are looking for.